# Magento 1.X Connect extension upload : "Version not found"

Tags: magento, magento-1.9

I am in Magento Connect, and I am trying to upload a new version for my Magento 1.X extension. After filling the fields and providing the archive, I get the error "An error occurred during upload to channel MagentoConnect: Version not found.".

FYI I put "1.1.0" in the version field, my file is named "myappname-1.1.0.tgz"...

Any idea?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Same thing is happening with me. Kindly let me know if you find a solution.

Comment: I wish. Some ideas: check the author typed when packaging is the same as the account screen name when uploading + try a new version number (apparently you have one chance with each). No more ideas on my side...

Comment: I have same issue. Anyone found exact solution?

Comment: Not yet :( I will give it a shot again this week...

Comment: Same technique, same output... Once again I followed https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4RfhYerEUIwUE9VX3FsT2t6V0U/view, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Check the 'Stability' value in you package.xml and what you select during the upload in Magento connect. Both should be same. You may be selecting 'Version Stability' as Stable while in your package it may be something else which would be causing the issue.

Comment: It might be the issue. I don't work for the company I did that for anymore, can't test, sorry :s Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You should also make sure that the Magneto Extension Name* is same as the  Extension Key in magento commerce while creating the package.

Your zip should have the name as your extension key, ignore the version number appended to the zip.

For example : 
Extension Key in magento commerce : **TestingMagento**

So while packaging enter name as : **TestingMagento**

Version Number : **1.0.0.0**

This will create your package extension as **TestingMagento-1.0.0.0.tgz**,  which you want to upload.